# Getting 'No changes detected in learning_log' in new Django project

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and django, and I'm following a tutorial from the Python Crash Course book 2nd edition, for creating a simple website. This is my first time using django. I am simply following along with the book, but I have run into a roadblock with the error 'No changes detected in learning_log'. I'm using django 2.2 for this project if that makes any difference.

Here are my installed apps in settings.py

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My Apps
    'learning_logs',
    # Default Apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]
```

Here is the DATABASES code in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # I had to change this from 'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'
        'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Note:
I changed

```
   'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'
```

to

```
   'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3')
```

to address a previous error: 'TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable'

To migrate the database I used python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs

```
(ll_env) PS C:\Users\Admin\documents\scripts\pythondir\learning_log> python manage.py > makemigrations learning_logs
```

this resolved the TypeError, but is still giving me the message 'No changes detected in app 'learning_logs''.

I used verbosity to give me more details and it gave me this information

```
(ll_env) PS C:\Users\Admin\documents\scripts\pythondir\learning_log> python manage.py makemigrations verbosity -v 3 learning_logs
usage: manage.py makemigrations [-h] [--dry-run] [--merge] [--empty] [--noinput] [-n NAME] [--no-header] [--check] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath >PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color] [--force-color]
                                [app_label ...]
manage.py makemigrations: error: unrecognized arguments: learning_logs
```

According to the book, what should happen is

```
Migrations for 'learning_logs':
  learning_logs/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - create model Topic
```

Additional info: 0001_initial.py is still being created.

I've already checked that my models definition is inheriting from django, per a suggesting for another user dealing with this problem, and it is.

I'd appreciate any ideas on what to try next.

ps. Apologies for any formatting errors, this is my first time posting on stack overflow.

Comment: The migrate with verbosity should go like: `python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs -v 3`. Keep `learning_logs` next to `makemigrations`

Comment: Also check if you already have the `0001_initial.py` file in `learning_logs/migrations/`. You could have already generated the migrations

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response bdbd. I corrected the order of the operations with verbosity, and it went back to giving me the 'No changes detected in learning_logs' message. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Ok cool. Did you check if the file is already in `learning_logs/migrations/`? If possible can you share your `models.py`

Comment: I do in fact have the ```0001_initial.py``` file in the learning_logs migrations folder, as I stated in my original question. Does that mean that ```python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs``` worked, if the file has been created?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. Yes it means the command was successful. If you do some changes in your models (maybe add another field), then `makemigrations` will detect changes and add another migration

Comment: Okay, so that's what 'no changes detected' means in this context. Thank you so much. I'm still unsure why I never got an initial message in the terminal telling me that migration was successful. Maybe because my first attempt resulted in a TypeError? Anyways, I just tried making a change and it logged it normally. I appreciate you helping me out.